# Power average of multinomial distribution

Tags: probability, expected-value, multinomial-distribution

Given a multinomial distribution
$$
X = \left(X_{1},\ldots,X_{K}\right),\
\sum_{k = 1}^KX_{k} = n,\quad\mbox{and}\quad
p_{1} = \cdots = p_{K} = \frac{1}{K},
$$
I wonder whether there is some approximation or lower bound (with respect to $K$, $n$, and $\alpha$) for the expected $\alpha$-power mean of $X$.

Specifically, I want to calculate the following:
$$
\mathbb{E}_X\left[\left(%
\sum_{k = 1}^{K}X_{k}^{\alpha}\right)^{1/\alpha}
\,\,\right]\quad \mbox{given}\ \alpha\in \left(1,2\right).
$$
I was checking the MGF of the multinomial distribution but I am not sure whether that is useful here. Any thoughts and ideas will be very helpful.